# Why is there only 414bytes in my mp4 file? (Xcode)(C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, video-capture

I designed a program that can record video from webcam by using OpenCV. However, when I check the saved file, I found out that there is only 414 bytes in it.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "cxcore.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
#define NUM_FRAME 300

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    CvVideoWriter* video=0;
    IplImage* frame=NULL;
    int n;
    if(!capture)
    {
        cout<<"Can not open the camera."<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        video=cvCreateVideoWriter("camera.mp4", CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), 10, cvSize(frame->width,frame->height),1);
        if(video)
        {
            cout<<"VideoWriter has created."<<endl;
        }
        cvNamedWindow("Camera Video",1);
        int i = 0;
        while(i <= NUM_FRAME)
        {
            frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
            if(!frame)
            {
                cout<<"Can not get frame from the capture."<<endl;
                break;
            }
            n=cvWriteFrame(video,frame);
            cout<<n<<endl;
            i++;
            if(cvWaitKey(2)>0)
                break;
        }
        cvReleaseVideoWriter(&video);
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is codes of my program. Is anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no divx codec installed on your machine.

in this case, VideoWriter only writes the mp4 header, and fails silently.

"Is anything wrong with the code ?"

not really. but you should not use the old c-api (IplImages, cv*Functions) any more. it won't be supported in the very near future.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im working on it. But when I try to save an avi file, it's still not working? Is that the same problem?

Comment: whether you call your file 'avi', 'asf','mp4', it does not matter. *what* matters is this: CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')  . you need another foucc code there, one that fits a codec installed on your box.

Comment: I know that. when i tried to use CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D') to save an avi file, it did not work.